# Application of the IVT

Tags: analysis

Is it true that on any circle there is a pair of opposite points where the age of the surface rock is the same?

I think the answer is no.  In the temperature case the function T: [ 0, 2π] → R where T(x)is the temperature at any given moment at the point on the equator with longitudinal angle x measured in radians is continuous, and T(0) = T(2π).  However when we consider the age of the rocks the function will not be continuous ?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the right answer here.